# An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the ListIdentities operation: IdentityPool 'ap-southeast-2:x' not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, federated-identity

I'm trying to get a list of users in AWS running the command:

> aws cognito-identity list-identities --max-results 60
>   --identity-pool-id ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Where 'ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxx' is found in AWS console/Federated Identities/Identity Browser.

My AWS CLI is set to default region ap-southeast-2 and the identity ID passed in is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a Cognito User Pool ID. Identity Pool and Cognito User Pool are separate things.

An identity pool ID is of the below format:

```
aws-region:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

To find the identity pool, go the AWS Cognito Console -> Manage Federated Identities.  To get the ID of the identity pool, click Edit.

Comment: I shoud have been more clear, that is how the id is formatted. This is the screen I'm getting the IDs from (let me know if I'm in the wrong place): https://i.imgur.com/kEzCNGb.png

Comment: you are trying to use the identities not the identity pool itself. Click on the "Edit Identity Pool" link on the top right corner in the same screenshot and use the displayed when you edit.

Comment: yep you were right! this aws ID stuff is so confusing hehe. thanks for your help!